# calling invoice destruct on shutdown

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice

I saw that in ce 1.9 [this method appeared](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php#L181) in the invoice model:

```
public function __construct()
{
    register_shutdown_function(array($this, 'destruct'));
    parent::__construct();
}
```

this meas the destruct method will be called when the execution ends, even if the page crashes for some reason.  In the destruct method the invoice is saved if `_saveBeforeDestruct` is set to `true`.
What I don't understand is the logic behind this.
let's say that `_saveBeforeDestruct` is set to `true` (this is set in the `canVoid` method), why do I need to save the invoice even if the script crashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is my best guess:**

There was a `__destruct` method in place before (see for example [here](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php#L181)).

I know that there are *certain* cases where destructor does not get called but the shutdown function gets executed. Therefore, if there is really a need to save the order at this point, I think `register_shutdown_function` is the better choice.

**So, why does the invoice needs to be saved when the script crashes?**

Again, a guess: I think/believe/hope this is due to integrity reasons. But I don't have an explanation why this is specifically related to the `canVoid` function only.

Edit: Nice question btw! Would love to get an explanation for this too and I hope someone who knows the *real* reason(s) can answer this :)